# unable to create react app with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, npm

I'm trying to create new react new app with typescript with the command

> npx  react-native init myApp --version 0.68.2 --template react-native-template-typescript

and I'm getting an error

> error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npm.taobao.org/react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript: [NOT_FOUND] react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript not found".

[image]

node version: **v16.10.0**

npm version:**7.24.0**

what I already tried to do

- run with different way:

> npx --ignore-existing react-native init MyApp --template
> react-native-template-typescript

- npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
- npm i -g @react-native-community/cli
- yarn remove global react-native-cli

nothing helped to solve this issue.

Comment: Looks like your custom NPM registry (`registry.npm.taobao.org`) doesn't have the template

Comment: how can I install this template? or what to do?

Comment: I'd talk to whoever is maintaining your custom registry to get it added. That or start using the default npm registry with `npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: The requested URL is incorrect. **It isn't a registry issue.** The correct URL should be `https://registry.npm.taobao.org/react-native-template-typescript`. Change a registry **WILL NOT** be a solution.

Comment: Try upgrading `node` and `npm` ant then try to install cli globally. As `-g` option is deprecated, you should now install it like this, `npm i --location=global @react-native-community/cli`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it seems like the template name is being picked up incorrectly for some reason

it should be looking for `https://registry.npmmirror.com/react-native-template-typescript` instead of `https://registry.npmmirror.com/react-native-template-react-native-template-typescript`

Can you try

`npx --ignore-existing react-native init MyApp --template typescript`

Since the taobao npm has been moved to npmmirror. [Reference](https://developpaper.com/new-domain-name-of-taobao-npm-mirror-station/)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```bash
$ npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

(w/o a version tag)

Answer (score -1):

can you try this line

```
npx --ignore-existing react-native init MyApp --template typescript
```

it should work to you